# Clickdetector is not a valid member of Model

Tags: lua, roblox

**Summarize the problem**
Clickdetector is not a valid member of Model.

**Describe what you’ve tried**
I've tried writing it in different ways, searched on google the cause but nothing solve it.

**When appropriate, show some code**
code that creates the clickdetector

```
local function Create()
    local ClickDetect = Instance.new('ClickDetector', game.Workspace.Tables.B.SegnalinoAttivo)
end

game.Workspace.Clients.Table2.CopyClick.OnServerEvent:Connect(Create)
```

code that shows the error (line 6)

```
local Clients = 0

local function ClientsNumber (player, num)
    wait(1)
    game.Workspace.Tables.B.SegnalinoAttivo:WaitForChild("ClickDetector")
    local ClickSegnalino = game.Workspace.Tables.B.SegnalinoAttivo.Clickdetector
    Clients = num
    print("Client at Table B = ")
    print(num)
    ClickSegnalino:Destroy()
    print("Destroyed the click detector")
    local ComeHereWait = Instance.new('Part', game.Workspace.Clients.Table2)
end

game.Workspace.Clients.Table2.RemoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(ClientsNumber)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect capitalization. Near the end of line 6, instead of ClickDetector, you put Click**d**etector

Comment: Oh... I feel stupid...
Btw thank you so much for the help!